# Efficiently calculate factorial in 32-bit machine

Tags: java, performance, factorial

How can I implement a function so that, given a number, it calculates the factorial. The given number would be a big number (e.g 100!) and I do not want to use java.math library.

Thanks!

Comment: regarding `how` part of your question I have two simple solutions in my mind   1. Using a simple loop e.g. factorial(3) would multiply numbers 3, 2, and 1. and 2. using a recursive function.

Comment: If efficiency is paramount download a suitably large number of pre calculated values and create a lookup table.

Comment: The biggest number will of course depend on whether you want `short factorial(int x)`, `int factorial(int x)`, `long factorial(int x)` or `BigInteger factorial(int x)`.

Comment: The Java code for s 32-bit machine is the same as for a 64-bit machines.  Your limit is how much memory you can address. How you optimise code depends on your context; i.e. why is this being done at all.  Usually factorial is used as part of a larger calculation and how you optimise it depends on how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

When using 32 bit integers, no matter if signed or unsigned, the largest factorial that can be represented is 12!=479001600. Considering that memory is cheap, an efficient implementation would be a lookup table:

```
static final int [] FACTORIALS =
    {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880,
     3628800, 39916800, 479001600 };

int factorial(int n) {
    return FACTORIALS[n];
}
```

Of course you should add some range checking for `n` here.

For larger factorials, use `BigInteger`.

Comment: You should probably pull out the array to a static constant; I wouldn't expect  Java to share it between different runs like other languages might.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Right, the `final` alone won't do. Have changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. The biggest factorial you can compute and still fit within a signed 32-bit integer is 12!
2. For factorials that will fit in a 32-bit integer you can use any algorithm you want. In fact, you can even look them up like so for optimal performance.

Like so

```
private static int factorial(int n) {
    final int f[] = {
        1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320,
        362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600
    };
    if (n < 1 || n > f.length+1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n");
    return f[n-1];
}
```

Comment: Your lookup table isn't right -- you get 13! wrong -- and more to the point, 13! doesn't fit into a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: yeah, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what datatype you're outputting to.  Remember, it's not the number of bits your machine uses that matters -- even on a 32-bit machine, a Java `long` will be 64 bits.

If you're outputting to either an `int` or a `long`, the *fastest* way to do it is just to have a static constant array of the correct factorial values and to look up the answer there.  That's about as cheap as it gets.  You can either manually put those constants in, or write

```
static final int[] factorials = {
   1,
   1,
   1 * 2,
   1 * 2 * 3,
   1 * 2 * 3 * 4,
   ...,
   1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10 * 11 * 12};
```

...and the compiler will compute those values at compile time for you.

If you want to output to a `BigInteger`...that's a little more interesting.  Guava's [`BigIntegerMath.factorial`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#factorial(int)) does some interesting stuff here; you might use it or try to reimplement it yourself.  Going from 1 to n, it...

- factors out powers of 2, counting them specially to be shifted back in at the end
- multiplies up numbers up to the point where they would overflow a `long`, at which point it converts the result to a `BigInteger` and adds it to a list
- divide-and-conquers multiplying the list out -- if it has four elements, a, b, c, d, it'd do `(a * b) * (c * d)`, so it splits the list in two, recursively multiplies, and then multiplies the results
- shifts back in the powers of 2 at the end